# Parsing values from core-response in Polymer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polymer, c3.js

I'm making a request for x and y values from a flax/python backend using Polymer and I can read the values in console for the XMLHttpResquest response, but now I need to convert the output into a set of discrete x and y values (so it can be read by C3.js - a framework sitting on top D3 for graphing).

Here's the code I'm using to get the XMLHttpResquest response:

```
<paper-button affirmative hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Submit</paper-button>

Polymer("add-graphItem",{

        addNewGraph: function () {

            var HeaderName = this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem.label;
            var FunctionName = this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem.label;
            console.log("The options are " +HeaderName +" and " +FunctionName);

            var params = {};
            if (this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem) {
                params['DataHeader'] = this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem.label;
            }
            if (this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem) {
                params['FunctionName'] = this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem.label;
            }
            this.$.sendOptions.params = JSON.stringify(params);
            var x = this.$.sendOptions.go();
            // this.$.sendOptions.go();
            console.log(x)

            // var ajax = document.querySelector("sendOptions");

            var results = [];
            this.addEventListener("core-response", 
                function(e) {
                    console.log(x.response);
                }
            );
        }
});
```

And here's an example of the output from `console.log(x.response);`:

```
{
  "graph": [
    {
      "Header": "MakeModeChange"
    }, 
    {
      "x": [
        0.0, 
        131.35, 
        26971.3, 
        27044.75, 
        27351.4, 
        27404.483333333334, 
        27419.416666666668, 
        33128.96666666667, 
        33549.13333333333, 
        34049.48333333333, 
        77464.26666666666, 
        77609.71666666666, 
        174171.85, 
        259166.98333333334
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "y": [
        1, 
        2, 
        3, 
        4, 
        5, 
        6, 
        7, 
        8, 
        9, 
        10, 
        11, 
        12, 
        13, 
        14
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Ultimately I need the output to look something like:

```
['x', 0.0, 131.35, 26971.3, 27044.75, 27351.4, 27404.483333333334...],
['y', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it - not recommended for large scale or if you don't fully trust the response values. Also, obvious, but if their api/data structures changes you're SOL.

```
xArr = JSON.parse(x.response).graph[1].x
xArr.unshift('x')

yArr = JSON.parse(y.response).graph[2].y
yArr.unshift('y')
```

You'll get both arrays you'll need, you can combine as needed